# How to resolve keyboard configuration problem following upgrade to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, dpkg

There has been a glitch in my latest upgrade of Ubuntu to 17.10.  A number of packages were not configured.  The starting point appears to be failure to configure the keyboard.  The rest appear to fail because of dependencies.

I tried running apt-get update; apt-get upgrade in the hope this might fix the problem but it failed again with the following error message:

> Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.166ubuntu7) ... archdetect: error
>   while loading shared libraries: libdebian-installer.so.4:       cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory dpkg: error
>   processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):  subprocess
>   installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
>   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core: 
>   xserver-xorg-core depends on keyboard-configuration; however:
>   Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet. ...

And so on through another 11 items.

The error message ends

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
keyboard-configuration 
xserver-xorg-core
xserver-xorg-video-radeon
xserver-xorg 
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
console-setup-linux 
xorg 
xserver-xorg-video-ati
console-setup
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau 
xserver-xorg-video-all
ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-minimal
E: Sub-process> /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As the message complained of the absence of libdebian-installer.so.4 I tried downloading that and running 'sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file' followed by 'sudo apt-get install -f'.  However the result was much the same except the failure of keyboard configuration was this time related to:

> Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.166ubuntu7) ... archdetect: error
>   while loading shared libraries: libdebian-installer.so.4: wrong ELF
>   class: ELFCLASS32 dpkg: error processing package
>   keyboard-configuration (--configure):  subprocess installed
>   post-installation script returned error exit status 127

By the way despite these reported failures the computer still appears to be working OK.  This does not appear to me to be related to the problems with fwupd as there is nothing in dmesg about fwupd and no problem reported loading the usb keyboard.

I am out of ideas.  Can someone tell me how to solve this configuration problem?